# Find X value from an exponential system using a given Y ratio

Tags: trigonometry

The blue lines being the lower half vertical FOV of a camera, the red line a laser line generator and the max value a wall, I want to calculate $X$ or $X'$ from a given $Y/Y'$ ratio. Here is the main system (seen from a vertical perspective) :

[image: http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc494/Golitan11/Outline_zpsxcth49zn.png]

I figured out that when the green line (random plane object) is perfectly centered between $X$ and $X'$, the ratio between $Y$ and $Y'$ is exactly the same as the ratio between min and max. So I would have something like this: $\min/0 < Y/Y' < 0/\max$.

How can I calculate $X$ or $X'$ using this given $Y/Y'$ ratio?

P.S. All the angles are in degrees and all the other values are in inches (except $Y$ and $Y'$, which are in pixels).

Comment: What do you mean by "an exponential system"? I don't see any exponentials.

Comment: Well the object distance has no constant correlation with laser offset from the center (the closer you are from the camera and the more the laser gets offset from the center in a non-constant way).

Comment: OK, but "non-constant" isn't the same as "exponential".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $y/x=\tan3.99$, $y'/x'=\tan41.49$, and $x+x'=22.11$. Divide the 2nd equation by the 1st to get $x'=x(y'/y)(\tan3.99/\tan41.49)$. Stick that into the 3rd equation to get $x(1+(y'/y)(\tan3.99/\tan41.49))=22.11$. So, $$x={22.11\over1+{y'\over y}{\tan3.99\over\tan41.49}}$$